# Can't Processing the XML response of a WCF service using XDocument

Tags: c#, wcf, linq-to-xml

I'm new to restful services and need help with a concern. I will be very grateful for any help you can give me, thanks.
I'm trying to implement a service operation that returns me my data in xml format.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/ObtenerRuc/{ruc}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
EmpresaData ObtenerRuc(string ruc);

[DataContract]
public class EmpresaData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string AD_COMPANY;
    [DataMember]
    public string AD_STREET;
    [DataMember]
    public string AD_CITY;
    [DataMember]
    public string AD_COUNTY;
    [DataMember]
    public string AD_PHONE;
    [DataMember]
    public string AD_E_MAIL;
    [DataMember]
    public string AD_TAX_ADMIN_NUM; 
}
```

In the treatment client application receiving the data into an XDocument

```
 ruc = XDocument.Load(new MemoryStream(e.Result));
```

and I get a xml file like this

[image]

My problem, when processing the XDocument

```
 string ciudad = ruc.Descendants("EmpresaData")
                    .ElementAt(0).Element("AD_CITY").Value.ToString();
```

The system displays the following error me

> Data from the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

[image]

Why reason can’t process the XDocument?
If anyone knows a solution that can implemented please, thanks.

Comment: What is `e.Result` and what data your have there?

Comment: e.Result is a DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs, and have bytes with xml response of wcf service

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error a few times in my own work, as I work with XML and JSON data a lot. It's likely to be an issue with the result you're getting back. If you can provide the XML string we can find the issue for you, but before you do check that you have valid XML headers, that you've got opening and closing elements in the XML string and that you've got no duplicate tags.